# Characters like ç, ´, ', are being turned into another ones, only into VScode

Tags: keyboard, key, custom-keyboard

After i pressed, by mistake, many keys of my keyboard, some thing activates and now, when i press "ç" i get ";", when i press ";" i get "/" and so on. I couldn't find anything to help me.
By the way, sorry, this is a silly question, but it is really annoying.

Pressed a key and VScode printed another one.

Key -(Turns Into)> Other Key

```
|   Key    | Turns Into |
| -------- | ---------- |
|   ;      |     /      |
|   ~      |     '      |
|   `      |     [      |
|   [      |     ]      |
|   '      |     `      |
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, it appears that after pressing the "many keys" on your keyboard, you accidentally pressed a keyboard shortcut that caused your operating system to start pretending that you are using a different keyboard layout than before. If you are on Windows, you must have accidentally hit the Windows key and space bar at the same time, which probably switched your keyboard layout to something like, say, a US keyboard. If you are using Windows, hitting the Windows key and the space key at the same time should reverse the change, and if it doesn't work the first time, do it again until it works again.

However, if you are using a Mac, I can't help you because I don't know what the equivalent keyboard shortcut is on MacOS.

Comment: I don't think that was the problem, because those wrong inputs were only occurring inside visual studio code.  

But, i don't know how, when i hit all keys together, i managed to press the combination again and it came back to normal. 

Thankyou very much for the time you took here.